# Cubrid DB for missions critical applications

Tags: database, scalability, cubrid

I wanted to know how many of you have heard or used Cubrid database?

1. How long Cubrid are in the DB business?
2. Any benchmarks available?
3. Does Cubrid can be used in production?
4. How easy is to scale with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the information you need in this presentation: [Growing in the wild. The story by CUBRID database developers.](http://www.slideshare.net/profyclub_ru/growing-in-the-wild-the-story-by-cubrid-database-developers-esen-sagynov-eugene-stoyanovic)